# Fix text alignment in MUI buttons?

Tags: material-ui

I love MUI but what bothers me alot is the fact that, in Icon Buttons, the space below and above the text never seem to be the same, i.e. the text never looks perfectly centered.

To visualize what I mean, I made an amazing Microsoft Paint image:

[image]

The buttons shown in the image are [from the docs](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-button/#buttons-with-icons-and-label).

Is there a generic fix I can apply?

The alignment with justifyContent inside the button looks fine to me. Maybe the problem is caused by the line-height?

Comment: I think you have something up with an installed browser extension or your theme/global CSS is causing that issue.  That same example from the docs on my screen (screen-shotted, copied into Figma, and zoomed in with grid lines) shows an even 12px above and 12px below the text -- not including the 1px for the top/bottom border. Tested on latest Firefox, Chrome, and Edge browsers. It does look off-center in your screenshot though.

Answer (score 0):

The possible solution for this will be, keep the text inside a span or div tag. Then apply the below css to that span or div.

```
  <Button  variant="outlined" startIcon={<DeleteIcon />}>
    <span className="text-alignment">Delete</span>
  </Button>
```

in the css file have this below code

```
.text-alignment{
   position: relative;
   top: 1.5px;
 }
```

here is a working [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/amazing-tamas-npvpjp?file=/demo.scss)